# How to remove all words written in capital letters ONLY (by using sed and/or awk)

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to delete all words written in capital letters only by using sed:

```
sed -r "s/\b[A-Z]\w*\s*//g" < file1 > file2
```

But this solution capture all the words starting with capital letters and delete them (this in not the goal).

Here's an example:

file1 content:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBbbbbb
AbAbAbAb
aaaaaBBBBB
AAAAAA BBBBBB
A1-B1
a1-b1
A1-b1 AA
AAAAA BBBBB AAAAA
Abbbb AAA
AAAAA AAAABB
Abbbb Baaaa Aaaaa AB
AAAAAA1
BBBBBBb
AAAAAA 1
BBBBBB b
```

Result should be like this (file2 content):

```
BBbbbbb
AbAbAbAb
aaaaaBBBBB
A1-B1
a1-b1
A1-b1 AA
Abbbb AAA
Abbbb Baaaa Aaaaa AB
AAAAAA1
BBBBBBb
AAAAAA 1
BBBBBB b
```

Each line of at least one digit or one lowercase letter should remain intact (should not be deleted).

Answer (score 5):

**Using egrep:**

```
egrep "[^[:upper:] ]" file
BBbbbbb
AbAbAbAb
aaaaaBBBBB
A1-B1
a1-b1
A1-b1 AA
Abbbb AAA
Abbbb Baaaa Aaaaa AB
AAAAAA1
BBBBBBb
AAAAAA 1
BBBBBB b
```

**OR using awk:**

```
awk '/[^[:upper:] ]/' file
```

**OR using sed:**

```
sed -n '/[^[:upper:] ]/p' file
```

Comment: @damienfrancois: Thanks, yes it was a typo

Comment: This `awk '/[^A-Z ]/'` does not work on my standard Ubuntu 12.4 due to local language that mess up `A-Z`. It more stable and portable to use `awk '/[^[:upper:] ]/' file`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk '! /^[[:space:][:upper:]]*$/' infile
```

It yields:

```
BBbbbbb
AbAbAbAb
aaaaaBBBBB
A1-B1
a1-b1
A1-b1 AA
Abbbb AAA
Abbbb Baaaa Aaaaa AB
AAAAAA1
BBBBBBb
AAAAAA 1
BBBBBB b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n "/[A-Z]/!p"
```

dont print line with at least 1 capital letter. Just check if empty line are to be include or not, in this case they are included.

Answer (score 1):

You weren't far off to begin with.  Start by getting rid of the `\w` from your regexp, it matches any alphanumeric.  Then only print non-empty lines.

```
sed -rn "s/\b[A-Z]+\s*//g; /[a-z0-9]/p" < file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Any line *without* a digit or lower case letter is deleted:

```
sed '/[[:digit:][:lower:]]/!d' file1 > file2
```